# Get login prompt for SQL reporting services deployment

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

Get login prompt for SQL reporting services deployment.

I really just want to deploy a report.

I have
-set my Web Service URL to be "ReportServer"

-I have tried several different service accounts.

-tried many different passwords for this dialog (but my understanding is if all is well you will not see this dialog)

What else do I need to try? What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

SSRS for SQL 2008 always requests authentication.  Use the Report Manager URL (servername/reports).  Someone will need to give you access to the report server via the Report Server UI or SSMS connecting to he Report Server.

There's a bunch of log info in the ReportServer folder in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS.MSSQLSERVER... that can show you why it's failing.  Also check out the application log.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly there's a sqlserver2005ReportingServicesWebServicesUser$ windows group. Try adding your admin in there. The rest of the security settings should be available from the reporting services page